# Calculating Average, while aggregating data

Tags: java

```
 MyObject structure is: 

public class MyObject { 
 String gender; 
 String state; 
  int quantity; 
  int Salary;}
```

I have the following function. It allows me to aggregate Data within the gender  and the state dimensions of my object:

```
   private static Collection<MyObject> aggregate(List<MyObject> objects) {

      int nombre=0;
      Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();

      for (MyObject current : objects) {
           String key = String.format("%s:%s", current.gender, current.state);
           MyObject aggregated = map.get(key);
           if (aggregated == null) {
              aggregated = new MyObject();
              aggregated.setGender(current.getGender());
              aggregated.setState(current.state);
              map.put(key, aggregated);

           }
           if(current.getSalary()!=0)
              nombre+=1;

           aggregated.setQuantity(aggregated.getQuantity() + current.getQuantity());
           aggregated.setSalary((aggregated.getSalary() + current.getSalary())/nombre);

        }
        return map.values();
  }
```

I'm looking to get the average salary for the aggregated data. Something is wrong with the "nombre" property.

Actually it gives me the following result:

```
 element : 1  M  40  1200
 element : 1  F  35  2000
 element : 1  M  20  200
 element : 1  M  80  300
 element : 1  F  35  2000
```

Content  after agregation:

```
`element : 1  M  140  333
 element : 1  F  70  2000`
```

but im expecting:

Content  after agregation: 
    `element : 1  M  140  566
     element : 1  F  70  2000`

Comment: If something is wrong then you need to tix something ;) - Seriously, be more specific: _what_ is wrong? Any error you get? Undesired output (if so then what do you expect and what do you get)?

Comment: What does `current.getSalary()` return?

Comment: @Thomas im not getting the desired output.
as you said, i want to calculate the average after summing all salaries, in the same time getSalary() returns an int value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  private static Collection<MyObject> aggregate(List<MyObject> objects) {
        Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();

        for (MyObject current : objects) {
         String key = String.format("%s:%s", current.gender, current.state);
           MyObject aggregated = map.get(key);
          if (aggregated == null) {
                aggregated = new MyObject();
               aggregated.setGender(current.getGender());
               aggregated.setState(current.state);
               map.put(key, aggregated);
          }
          aggregated.nombre+=1;
           aggregated.setQuantity(aggregated.getQuantity() + current.getQuantity());
            aggregated.setSalary((aggregated.getSalary() + current.getSalary()));

         }
            for(MyObject c : map.values()){
            c.setSalary(c.getSalary()/c.nombre);

        }

        return map.values();
    }
```

i have added an attribute nombre to MyObject.

Answer (score 2):

I see at least four problems here:

1. If the current salary is 0 you count it anyways and if it is the first you delete by 0 - ouch.
2. `nombre` is an `int` and assuming `getSalary()` also returns an `int` you get truncation/rounding issues since 1/2 = 0 when all operands are integers.
3. You probably want to calculate the average *after* summing all salaries, not for each iteration.
4. You seem to aggregate based on gender and status but you only have one counter (`nombre`) for all. You'll want to have a counter per aggregate.

Comment: i have edited my post, so you can understand better.

Comment: @hamzaspecter if the 4th point is what you need then go ahead and implement it. I'm sure you know how to keep track of multiple counts. Also at least implement the 3rd point as well.

Comment: i need to implement the 4th one, then the third one will come straight forward.
i don't know how to deal with multiple counter per aggregate.
i will appreciate if you can inspire me with an idea

Comment: @hamzaspecter ok, there are multiple ways, I'll name 2: 1) Create a wrapper for the aggregates that contains the count and use that wrapper in the map. In the end extract the aggregates from the wrappers and put them into the result list. 2) use a second map with the same key and an `Integer` value. To increment it you need to extract the value (if there is none then create one), add 1 and put it into the map again.